Laplace Transform and Different Results
I have the following piecewise function and I take the Laplace Transform
  f1[t_] := Piecewise[{{t^2, 0 <= t <= 1}, {Sin[2 t], 1 < t <= Pi}, {Cos[t], t > Pi}}];
  
  f1[t]

  LaplaceTransform[f1[t], t, s] // Simplify

I then manually write that function using unit step functions and do the same as above
  f2[t_] := t^2*(UnitStep[t] - UnitStep[-1 + t]) + Sin[2*t]*(UnitStep[-1 + t] - UnitStep[-Pi +
            t]) + Cos[t]*UnitStep[-Pi + t];
  
  f2[t]

  LaplaceTransform[f2[t], t, s] // Simplify

I then use Mathematica's built-in approach to find the Unit Step expansion (compare to the above)
  f3[t_]:=Simplify`SimplifyUnitStep[Simplify`PWToUnitStep[f1@t]];

  f3[t]

  f3[t_]:=Simplify`SimplifyUnitStep[Simplify`PWToUnitStep[f1@t]]//Simplify

The first and third results match, but I cannot see if the second approach does. What am I missing? Is there a way to get the first and third results to match the second as it is simpler to read? I tried trig expand, trig reduce, full simplify and cannot get them to match.

You wrote your f2 manually wrongly.

UnitStep[-Pi t] should be UnitStep[-Pi+t] in the definition of f2.

That is just a copy and paste error - corrected.

I am not sure what you are asking. Do you what to know it the three definitions are equivalent or how to transform first definition into second?

@azerbajdzan: Thank you.  I want to see that all three results match. I preferably want to see all three of them the way the second result is because that is much easier on the eyes.

You see that f1 and f3 are equivalent.
f1,f2 and  f3 are equivalent only except discontinuities t=1, t=π.
ForAll[t, {}, 
  f1[t] == f3[t] // PiecewiseExpand // FullSimplify] // Resolve

ForAll[t, {}, 
  f1[t] == f2[t] == f3[t] // PiecewiseExpand // 
   FullSimplify] // Resolve

ForAll[t, {t != 1, t != π}, 
  f1[t] == f2[t] == f3[t] // PiecewiseExpand // 
   FullSimplify] // Resolve


True

False

True

You have to define another piecewise function f4 that matches f2 unconditionally. I changed some inequalities from >= to > and vice versa.
f4[t_] := 
  Piecewise[{{t^2, 0 <= t < 1}, {Sin[2 t], 1 <= t < π}, {Cos[t], t >= π}}];

ForAll[t, {}, f2[t] == f4[t] // PiecewiseExpand // FullSimplify] // Resolve


True


Thank you. What I don't understand is why $f1, f2, f3$ do not provide the same result. Even with your note regarding the discontinuities, shouldn't the three results line up based on theory?

What you mean by "they do not provide the same result"? Do you understand where the difference is between my f4 and your f1?

The Laplace transforms of all three f1, f2, f3 are the same as it does not depend on the values at discontinuities.

I missed that. Thank you!
